# PHP - WWW website pre-fix and no pre-fix use different SESSION variables

Tags: php, session, url, no-www

When visiting my website using the `www` prefix from the no-www version (which I normally use) I find that I am no longer logged in... Why is this?

Is there a way to have the two versions of the site use the same `SESSION` variable or at least redirect to one version so as to prevent internal redirects switching users from one version to another (all my redirect use relative paths so I don't think it would be an issue, but I'm inexperienced so I don't know for sure)?

Comment: www. vs. non-www: session-cookie domain settings. But forcefully redirecting all users to one or the other (pick one, stick with it) is the preferred solution as it has a multitude of other benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Redirecting it to one place (i.e. www.example.com) will help with the SEO and also fix your issue of different session variables as it will always fall under www version.

Comment: I wish to only use the no-www version of the site, so how will I format that code to fit (i.e. what do I replace)?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using www version instead of the non, much more benefits. As for thr file structure, create a `.htaccess` file on the root level of your application and add the above code. It should kick in

Comment: With `example.com`? I don't need to put in my website's URL?

Comment: Lol yes you do, change example.com to whatever you want. Just a note if you do want to change it so everything falls on non-www, then just change the URL's around